# Sharing ViewModel's Property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, properties, viewmodel

### Goal

To have a DataGrid in my MainWindow.xaml contain whatever I add in another Window.xaml's ViewModel Property.

[image: Adding DamagedItem to Window.xaml]

I am looking how to display the exact information in my MainWindow's DataGrid.

---

### Background Information

1. MainWindow.xaml has a DataContext to ViewModel **InspectionViewModel.vb**
2. Window.xaml has a DataContext to ViewModel **DamagedItemViewModel.vb**

   - My ViewModel contains an `ObservableCollection` of my Model: **DamagedItemModel.vb**

I want to be able to gather whatever is on my ObservableCollection and put it into my MainWindow's DataGrid's ItemSource. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my **DamagedItemViewModel** I shared the public property so that I could access it from my **InspectionViewModel**.

### InspectionViewModel Modifications

I made my ViewModel inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` and added the same `ObservableCollection` property that my DamagedItemViewModel contained. Once the user was finished with the Window.xaml, I just assign the **DamagedItemViewModel.DamagedItems** to my **InspectionViewModel.DamagedItems**.

```
DamagedItems = DamagedItemViewModel.DamagedItems
```